# Creating a full replica/offline copy of the public pypi repository

Tags: nexus, nexus3

Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.9.0-01.

I wish to create a 'proxy' Nexus repository that will a replica of the [public pypi repository](https://pypi.org/). The other machines can then be configured to point to this Nexus repo. so that a 'pip install' on these machines works even if there is no Internet connection. Accordingly, I created a proxy repository of type 'pypi(proxy)'.

[image]
[image]

When I browse this repo, there aren't any components/assets but whenever someone does a 'pip install' by pointing to this repo, the package shows up in the interface e.g: `pip install --user pyspark --verbose`
[image]

What I am looking for is to clone/copy all the packages in the PyPI repository at once so that the future 'pip install' refers to this local copy and doesn't go to the Internet every time. Once a day, the local copy should be updated.

Is it possible to do so in Nexus OSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is a PyPI mirror repository, not a proxy.

The PyPI proxy repository behaviour you described is correct, because it is a proxy, not a mirror. Nexus Repository Manager does not provide functionality to to create a mirror of another repository.

However, you could try to use a PyPI mirror client (e.g. [bandersnatch](https://github.com/pypa/bandersnatch/)) to obtain a copy of all packages, then move those files over to your **PyPI hosted** repository and ask Nexus to reindex the files. Later you would have to periodically repeat the process to keep your mirror up to date.

Comment: > move those files over to your PyPI hosted => how does one "move" these files over to the Nexus repo? Using twine, you mean, file by file? Or is there a better way? Thanks!